# IIS authenticated users can't log in to website

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, iis

I have deployed some website on corporate intranet, on virtual web server IIS. I need to capture the windows login for each person who is opening the website, and can't get it to work.
If I enable authentication with windows, it opens the website and recognize my login, but for any other user it is asking for credentials, and even if provided, throws Error 401 ?
Do you know what can cause that ?

Is there a better way to capture the windows login from the machine that is opening the website ?

Thanks!

Comment: `Is there a better way?` Well, you haven't told us how you're doing it. Describe your IIS configuration, provide relevant samples from your web.config file. Don't assume we know exactly what you're doing.

Comment: Post your web-config and the code your using....